# Working with CONCAT and NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql

Why is my entire string blank when I output data using php doing:

```
select concat(name, desc) as output from reports where type=2
```

And the data in the table is:

```
Name Desc
a    desc a
b    null
c    null
```

Output using php:

```
a desc a
blank space
blank space
```

If I didn't use `concat`, the output is as usual. I'm using `concat` so I can output everything in one variable when using php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `CONCAT_WS()`

```
concat_ws('', name, `desc`)
```

or with `COALESCE()`

```
concat(name, COALESCE(`desc`,''))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c125/3)

Comment: the link for verifying is good.. But you can also put the whole example here in the answer too to make this answer more re-presentable. Because the link can die in future.. :)